# Matching Data Attributes in Two Seperate Sliders

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using two separate sliders, one to display images and the other to display corresponding text. The slider with the text needs to be showing all of the text all the time, with just the text that has the same data-attribute as the current slide from the first slider to change color by adding an "active" class. Since all the text has to be displayed no matter what image is being shown from the first slider, I cannot combine the two sliders.

My question is how do I match up two data-attributes from two separate sliders to add the active class to just one element in the second slider.

Here is my code so far:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('.flexslider').flexslider({
            animation: "fade"
        });


        // if the class .flex-active-slide is being used on an li
        // if data-roles are the same #
        if ('ul.slides li.flex-active-slide' && 'ul.slides li[data-role] == ul.slider-text li[data-role]') {

            // add active class to selected li in second slider
            jQuery("ul.slider-text li").addClass('active');
        }
    });


#########SLIDER 1 #################


<div class="flexslider">
        <ul class="slides">
            <li data-role="1"><img src="/media/island/content/cool-places/1_PARROT_CAY.jpg"/></li>
            <li data-role="2"><img src="/media/island/content/cool-places/2_CUISINART.jpg"/></li>
            <li data-role="3"><img src="/media/island/content/cool-places/3_LITTLE_PALM.jpg"/></li>
            <li data-role="4"><img src="/media/island/content/cool-places/4_RITZ_CAYMAN.jpg"/></li>
            <li data-role="5"><img src="/media/island/content/cool-places/5_REGENT.jpg"/></li>
            <li data-role="6"><img src="/media/island/content/cool-places/6_KIAWAH.jpg"/></li>
            <li data-role="7"><img src="/media/island/content/cool-places/7_FOUR_SEASONS.jpg"/></li>
            <li data-role="8"><img src="/media/island/content/cool-places/8_SEA_ISLAND.jpg"/></li>
            <li data-role="9"><img src="/media/island/content/cool-places/9_CHEECA.jpg"/></li>
            <li data-role="10"><img src="/media/island/content/cool-places/10_RITZ_NAPLES.jpg"/></li>
            <li data-role="11"><img src="/media/island/content/cool-places/11_PINK_SANDS.jpg"/></li>
        </ul>
    </div>


############### SLIDER 2 #####################

<ul class="slider-text">
        <li data-role="1"><p class="uppercase">parrot cay &bull; turks and caicos</p></li>
        <li data-role="2"><p class="uppercase">sea island golf club &bull; sea island</p></li>
        <li data-role="3"><p class="uppercase">ritz carlton &bull; naples</p></li>
        <li data-role="4"><p class="uppercase">cheeca lodge &bull; islamorada</p></li>
        <li data-role="5"><p class="uppercase">ritz carlton &bull; grand cayman</p></li>
        <li data-role="6"><p class="uppercase">four seasons &bull; palm beach</p></li>
        <li data-role="7"><p class="uppercase">little palm island &bull; little torch key</p></li>
        <li data-role="8"><p class="uppercase">kiawah island golf resort &bull; kiawah island</p></li>
        <li data-role="9"><p class="uppercase">regent palms &bull; turks & caicos</p></li>
        <li data-role="10"><p class="uppercase">cuisinart &bull; anguilla</p></li>
        <li data-role="11"><p class="uppercase">pink sands resort &bull; harbor island</p></li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First let me start by asking if the second list needs to be displayed at all times, why does it need to be a slider?

Regardless, it sounds like what you want to do is add a custom control nav. This can be accomplished by adding the property [`manualControls`](https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/wiki/FlexSlider-Properties) to the init object, like so:

```
jQuery('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "fade",
    manualControls: '.slider-text li'
});
```

This will link the slider to the control nav and they should share classes and states. I believe the order in which the control nav is setup should match the cooresponding slide order for the flexslider (the index for the nav item should match the index for the slide).

Once this is set up, you should have active states for both the slide and the control nav that you can style accordingly. Hope this helps!

Comment: Yeah I guess the second ul doesn't really need to be a slider. I guess it can just stay as a normal ul with list elements that always show. And the only thing that changes as the first slider changes is the corresponding name and it's text color